# How can I ensure only a single instance of a Form will be opened?

Tags: c#, winforms

On button click, I open a new form (lets say Form2), but I don't want that Form2 to open more than 1time. And I don't want to use .ShowDialog(), because it wont allow me to go to the Previous Form. How can I do that ?

Comment: use flag (`bool` variable)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to check if form already opened:

```
if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Any())
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: won't work if you want to open 2 form1 and to have for each form2 opened ^^

Comment: @Sinatr question sounds like about having single instance of Form2

Comment: @Sinatr, and where in the world did that requirement come from?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky And that's probably not actually appropriate, it's more likely that it should behave as Sinatar described.

Comment: @all, i m just jelous because of the others typing skills.

Answer (score 2):

You can show existing form instead of creating new:

```
Form2 _form2 = null;

void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
     if (_form2 == null)
     {
         _form2 = new Form2();  
         _form2.Closed += Form2_Closed;
     } 

     _form2.Show();
     _form2.BringToFront(); 
 }

private void Form2_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _form2 = null;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just a null check, you could check the `Visible` property.

Comment: @Ginosaji By setting it to null you allow the GC to reclaim the form when it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the `Show` method, which will show the form and allow the users to get back to the form, but then you can also override the `OnClosing` event of the form:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

and that will keep the users from being able to **literally close the form.** Finally, if you wanted, you could `Hide` the form when the user closes it:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

and then you'll need to hold on to that instance in the first form so that you can re-show it when the button is clicked. So in the first form you might have a class field like this:

```
private Form2 _form2 = new Form2();
```

and then in the button click it would look like this:

```
_form2.Show();
```

and since they can't actually close the form this will always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
bool windowIsNotOpen;

Mutex mutext = new Mutex(true, "Form2", out windowIsNotOpen);

if (!windowIsNotOpen)
{
    // Form2 is already open
    return;
}
```

Comment: Mutex .... Why Mutex ? Mutex is OS wide and comes with a cost , I think , you are confused with single instance of an application , don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a static property that tells you whether it's open or not. You'd set it when the form is opened, and turn it off when the form is closed.

```
class Form2 {
    public static bool IsOpen { get;set; }
    public Form2() {
        Load += (sender, e) => { Form2.IsOpen = true; };
        Closed += (sender, e) => { Form2.IsOpen = false; };
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to open it, check the flag first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Form2 f;

    bool isOpen = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f == null)
        {
            f = new Form2(); ;
            f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f_FormClosed);
        }
        if (!isOpen)
        {
            isOpen = true;
            f.Show();
        }

    }

    void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        isOpen = false;
    }
```

> Try this or use Application.OpenForms and check which one opened